# HTAccess Redirect and Remove File+Extension

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, redirect

If the user types

```
www.example.com/Front
```

OR

```
www.example.com/Front.php
```

I want to redirect to

```
www.example.com
```

Here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex Front.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^.]+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But for some reason, when I type `www.example.com/Front.php` the page loads but the url doesn't change, it stays as `/Front.php`. What do I need to add/change to make it redirect properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule does not match your URL. So nothing happens with rewriting here.

Your URL is `Front.php` (no slash at the start because you are inside a .htaccess file). The regex is `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^.]+)\.php$` - this does not match because there is no slash in your url, apart from other things.

Not triggering the regex in the RewriteRule results in the complete rule including all preceding RewriteCond to be ignored.

If your .htacces does not have more rules, then this is it.

You should enable the RewriteLog to see whats going on.